# Predefined and random object placement algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx

I have replicated the classic [helicopter game](http://www.addictinggames.com/action-games/helicoptergame.jsp) using libgdx. It was fairly easy. Now I want to modify it such a way that the obstacles placement will be a mixture of predefined and randomly generated positions. This way I can also place coins with nice patterns for the predefined groups of obstacles.

To do that, I need to have imaginary grids in the screen using the obstacle size. Then create some groups of predefined positions for both obstacles and coins. Maybe create 10 sets of those predefined levels. Show them once in a certain period of time randomly for the players to have a different feel.

My question is how do I create imaginary grids on a phone screen considering different sizes, resoultion, and densities?

N.B. Please don't give me links of android developer pages for reading on different sizes and how to handle them. I have read many times and still do read once in a while.

Comment: what do you mean by depth? Is this a 3d game?

Comment: @Kevin - my apologies. I meant "densities".

Comment: Is it possible to use the height and width of the screen to do this? e.g. if you wanted an 8 by 8 grid, would it work to draw the lines at (height/7) * 1, (height/7) *2, etc.? (Note if you wanted 8 columns on a screen you would only need to draw 7 lines). This should account for resolution as height and width would be in pixels

Comment: @Accipheran - Hi! Can you please elaborate a little more on "This should account for resolution as height and width would be in pixels" before I give my thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, what really matters is not the height and width of the screen in inches, but really how many pixels tall and how many pixels wide it is. So if the height of the screen you're working with is, say, 320 pixels, it makes no difference whether those pixels are spread out over 2 inches or 3 inches etc. You'll just know that the height of every box in your grid (if, say, you want an 8x8 grid) will be 320/8 = 40 pixels. The phone screen will determine whether those 40 pixels will be make-up 1/4" or 3/8" (etc.) of the screen, so you the developer don't have to worry about it

Comment: @Accipheran - Let's say my obstacle image is 20 (Width) by 40 (Height) pixels. If I take your example, my obstacle will fit in the grid. I can put 8 obstacles in one column and 8*8 = 64 obstacles in total?

Comment: Correct, provided the width of the screen you're working with is at least 160 pixels (working from the example)

Comment: @Accipheran Can you please post your comments as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can account for different size screens by using relative instead of absolute values for your grid. E.g., you can set the height of a cell to be screenHeight/8, rather than "40". This way, whether the screen is 320 pixels or 400 pixels tall, you can still be sure that your grid will be 8 "boxes" tall.